# Exception not caught by OkHttp4 even inside a try-catch block

Tags: android, okhttp

Exception not caught by OkHttp4 even inside a try-catch block

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "test.dig.dev.br": No address associated with hostname
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
       at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.java:5)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:130)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:20)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:17)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:197)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:51)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.java:31)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:11)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:162)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:194)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:162)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:167)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:162)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:34)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:162)
       at br.dev.dig.api.intercetptor.DeviceInterceptor.intercept(DeviceInterceptor.java:13)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:162)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.java:113)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.java:33)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Caused by android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
       at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Linux.java)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:133)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:222)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:133)
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
       at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.java:5)
       [...] same as above
```

I'm using OkHttp 4.10.0 to handle my app REST requests, but, somehow, I'm capturing this crash in Crashlytics.

Looking down at stacktrace, `AsyncCall.run()` is the point where the thread resume on non-platform side, whose class is in OkHttp side..

Looking at [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-4.10.0/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealCall.kt#L512), and looking forward in stacktrace, the next function called was `getResponseWithInterceptorChain()` at line [517](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-4.10.0/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealCall.kt#L517). This call is inside a `try-catch` block and the first catch is exactly for `IOException`, which is base of [`UnknownHostException`](https://devdocs.io/openjdk%7E8/java/net/unknownhostexception).

How it is possible? And how to correct handle this?

Comment: Post your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RickyMo I don't think that require my code, since only one function is mine, all others are system or OkHttp, and references for OkHttp are marked as link to their source.